# Json authentication in spring boot with flutter front end

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flutter, spring-security

I am trying to make a log in page in spring boot with a flutter front end by sending the username and password through JSON. The IP sends the request from my android emulator to localhost.

The following flutter code runs when a submit button is pressed:

```
Future<String> sendLogin(
    String username, String password, BuildContext context) async {
  var url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/login";
  var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
      headers: <String, String>{"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        "username": username,
        "password": password,
      }));
  url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/protected-resource";
  response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  return response.body;

}
```

My spring boot back-end looks like this

-Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true,
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyAuthenticationProvider authProvider;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CustomFilter mupaf = new CustomFilter();
        mupaf.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilterAt(
                    mupaf,
                  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/h2/**")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/protected-resource").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
        http.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

}
```

The custom filter:

```
public class CustomFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

protected CustomFilter() {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

    String username, password;

    try {
        Map<String, String> requestMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), Map.class);
        username = requestMap.get("username");
        password = requestMap.get("password");
        System.out.println(username+ " "+password+" Tried to log in");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            username, password);

    return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
}
```

}

Authentication provider:

```
 @Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {


    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken upAuth = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        final String name = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();

        final String password = (String) upAuth.getCredentials();

        final String storedPassword = userRepository.findByUsername(name).map(User::getPassword)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BadCredentialsException("illegal id or passowrd"));

        if (Objects.equals(password, "") || !Objects.equals(password, storedPassword)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("illegal id or passowrd");
        }

        final Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                principal, authentication.getCredentials(),
                Collections.emptyList());
        result.setDetails(authentication.getDetails());

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I send a username and password through postman I am able to log in and access protected resources. But when I do the same through the flutter front end, the log in is successful but the protected resource can't be accessed (Error 403).

What am I missing here that causes the issue?

Comment: You should probably consider using a Token-based authorization as you're not storing a session in your Flutter app

Comment: Not a flutter guru, but it was for Angular, you need to have an interceptor that will inject your JWT token in following requests after login request